# evaluate sum in item teplate's label in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am creating edit,delete to gridview.

For that i am using item templates.

i have used following code to bind the data to database:

```
da = New SqlDataAdapter("select expDate,sum(Amount) from expence_VB where expDate between '" + DateTime.Parse(txtFromDate.Text) + "' and '" + DateTime.Parse(txtToDate.Text) + "' group by ExpDate", con)
            ds = New DataSet()
            da.Fill(ds)
            gv.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            gv.DataBind()
```

I am using template field as :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount" >

                <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:Label ID="lblAmount" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("amount") %>'></asp:Label> 


                </ItemTemplate> 

                <EditItemTemplate>

                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount"  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("amount") %>'></asp:TextBox>

                </EditItemTemplate> 


                </asp:TemplateField>
```

In this there is field `sum(Amount)`. which i want to use in above evaluation.[in template fields as eval[..]]

How to use it?

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood you correctly but I will try to help

Add alias for columns `sum(amount)` in your query so it would be easier accessible in `DataSet`

```
da = New SqlDataAdapter("select expDate, sum(Amount) as amount ...)
```

and then in your asp.net code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount"  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("amount") %>'>
```

> Note: you should use parametrized queries for safety